# Finding path between pages on wiki doesn't work with larger paths

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a program which taken an input wikipedia link and clicks on the first link. The program will continue to run until it matches the second input. I will eventually add in functionality to terminate the program when it hits a loop.

Right now my code is working for examples with only a few links such as Bee -> History but gives me an error for longer paths. Here is the code, I would appreciate any input I just started to study ruby yesterday and likely have mistakes.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

puts "Enter starting page (full URL not needed): "
page1 = gets.chomp

puts "Enter ending page (full URL not needed): "
page2 = gets.chomp

until page1 == page2 do
  #open page
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + page1))

  %w[.//table .//span .//sup .//i].map {|n| doc.xpath(n).map(&:remove) }

  #find href in first p
  fp = doc.css("p").first.search('a').map{ |a| a['href']}

  #make page1 = the end of the url. ex. /wiki/link = link
  page1 = fp.first[6,fp.first.length]
  puts page1
end
```

Updated: Here is the error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\files>ruby 121.rb
Enter starting page (full URL not needed):
Cow
Enter ending page (full URL not needed):
Philosophy
Domestication
Latin_(language)
Classical_antiquity
History
121.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError
)
```

Comment: What error are your program output ? If it is possible, add stacktrace.

Comment: I have added the error msg

Comment: It seems, that in `fp = doc.css("p").first.search('a').map{ |a| a['href']}` at first `p`, program can`t find tags `a`. May be you should search in other `p` (investigate structure of wiki pages, that causes error) ? Or just ignore it -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, for solve your task, you can treat all links on the page to achieve page2:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

puts "Enter starting page (full URL not needed): "
start_page = gets.chomp

puts "Enter ending page (full URL not needed): "
end_page = gets.chomp

pages = [start_page]
next_page = pages.first

until next_page == end_page or pages.empty? do
  next_page = pages.pop
  puts "Treat: #{next_page}"

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + next_page))

  %w[.//table .//span .//sup .//i].map {|n| doc.xpath(n).map(&:remove) }

 doc.css("p").each do |p| 
  p.search('a').each{ |a| pages.push a['href'][6, a['href'].length]}
 end

end
```